# trying to do a stride test of the cache but program is not ending

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I am trying to do a stride test of the cache but there is an error in my code that is causing the program to never end. I am having to terminate my file by myself. It should be a simple error in the code but I really can not find where it is. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <fstream>
#include<time.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(argc!=3)
  {
    cout<<"Usage is: "<<argv[0]<< " [stride] [steps]"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }


  int stride = atoi(argv[1]);
  int steps  = atoi(argv[2]);

  int totalSize = stride * steps;

  // print some info about the system
  cout<<"size of int: "<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
  cout<<"stride: "<<stride<<endl;
  cout<<"total size: "<<totalSize<<endl;

  byte *dataArray = new byte[totalSize];

//  init array data
    //for(int i=0;i<totalSize;i++)
    //  dataArray[i] = 1;

  // traverse array and measure time
  struct timespec start, stop;

  //save start time 
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start);

  long result = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<totalSize;i + stride)
    {
        result += dataArray[i];
    }

  for(int i=0;i<totalSize;i+=stride)
      result += dataArray[i];

  //save end time 
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &stop);
  ofstream myfile;
 // myfile.open("data.csv");

  // calc elapsed time
  double cpuTime = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1e6 + (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1e3;    // in micros
 // myfile << "%d",cpuTime;
 // myfile.close();
  // report results
  cout<<"Calculation: "<<result<<endl;
  cout<<"CPU time micro: "<<cpuTime<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as typo: `;i + stride` should be `;i += stride`. Btw. the compiler should be warning you about the fact that the `i + stride` expression is not doing anything. If it didn't, [enable more warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) in your compiler. And furthermore you should learn how to use a *debugger*, which would have been able to show you where and why the loop keeps iterating.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<totalSize;i + stride)
```

You never increment `i`.